# JSON Parsing Syntax - Simple PHP

Tags: php, json

I have the following json output - I've tried multiple things however not having any luck - I just want to get the value for kind (software-package). Any ideas:

```
{"items":
[{"assets":
[{"kind":"software-package","url":"__URL__"}],
"metadata":{"bundle-identifier":"SimpleCalculator",
"bundle-version":"000","kind":"software",
"title":"com.work.demo","subtitle":"1.0"}
```

Thanks,

Comment: If it is typo, you could use json_decode, otherwise take it as string and use preg_match and regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to decode it with `json_encode` like

```
$result_arr = json_decode($my_arr,true);
print_r($result_arr['items']['assets']['kind']);
```

Comment: missed `true` as second argument. And the path seems not correct

Comment: `items` and `assets` are array. so `$result['items'][0]['assets'][0]`

Answer (score 0):

That is not valid JSON.

Lets attempts to format that a little more sensibly.

```
{"items": [
    {"assets": [
        {"kind":"software-package","url":"__URL__"}
     ],
     "metadata":{"bundle-identifier":"SimpleCalculator",
                 "bundle-version":"000","kind":"software",
                 "title":"com.work.demo","subtitle":"1.0"
                }
```

You're missing a lot of closing brackets. :(

How are you acquiring this JSON. Is it hand formatted or generated by some software? They're may be bugs in the source, and not your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version of PHP above 5.3 then there are built-in functions to decode and encode JSON strings already.

```
$some_json_string = {......};
$json_string_as_object = json_decode($some_json_string);
$json_string_as_array = json_decode($some_json_string, true);
```

You can also do the reverse:

```
$some_array = array(...);
$json_string = json_encode($some_array);
```

Json Decode : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
Json Encode: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php